# In what parts of the world is it impossible to view the night sky due to light pollution?

Tags: observational-astronomy, milky-way, light-pollution, night-sky

Growing up far from any city, I have always been able to view the full night sky. It was just the way how things were. Of course, I knew that light pollution is a thing, and that the sky is a lot less clear if you live in a city.

It just never occurred to how bad it was before talking with people who had experienced it.

Apparently:

- Inside a city, it is pretty much impossible to view anything.
- It is not a lot better just outside a city, the sky is still mostly empty.
- Most of Europe, parts of the US, India, and eastern Asia is so polluted with light that you can not see the Milky way.

Does anyone have a map showing the affected area? How many people have never seen our own galaxy?

Comment: Even 50 miles away from NYC you can still see a strong glow on the horizon that makes it hard to see even the brightest stars.

Comment: I live in Berlin/Germany and when there are no clouds above, I can easily spot Big Dipper. Orion and thousands of other stars. But I can't see Milky Way or Andromeda. 50 years ago out on the country I've seen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a recent study on this, based on satellite and ground observations around the world.

According to [the paper](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/6/e1600377.full):

> The Milky Way is hidden from more than one-third of humanity, including 60% of Europeans and nearly 80% of North Americans.

And there's a map: [The New World Atlas of Artificial Sky Brightness](http://cires.colorado.edu/Artificial-light). This is probably the most accurate and up to date light pollution map we have at the moment.

The percentages are based on population density, I don't know of any numbers for individuals.

Answer (score 6):

Googling for 'light pollution map' gives a pretty good looking [result](http://www.lightpollutionmap.info/). Those things usually are created using satellite measurments that are susceptible to scattered light (by measuring the polarity of light) in order to separate direct illumination from actual light pollution.

I also suggest you visit a city and then compare the light pollution index on this site to what you know as home, in order to get a feeling for the severity of the numbers.

I cannot answer your question about how many people have never seen our galaxy, as this is a function of travel willingness of each individual living in a city and therefore maybe even impossible to answer for our intelligence agencies.